# How much money is needed for a Canada visitor visa?

Tags: visas, canada, standard-visitor-visas

I would like to visit Canada for a birthday party of my nephews, but the agents are saying that the Canadian Embassy requires $8000 CAD in my bank account before I can get a visitor visa for Canada. Please advise me if this is correct information or not. If not please provide me any good travel agent address in Punjab.

Comment: How long did you say you would visit Canada for? You have to show enough finances to support yourself during your trip but 8,000 sounds like far too much for a short trip

Comment: I’d change your agent, they are misleading you

Comment: There is not standard value, and it the amount is not just to support yourself, it should show that you will not have financial problem by taking the travel (else: it is a red flag for looking to work). In any case: show what you have, honestly. Cash parking (borrowing cash) is a receipt of visa deny. Note: funds is only one minor part of overall evaluation. You must check all points. Some very strong points could help on the weak points.

Comment: That agent lied to you. Discontinue any contact with them and DO NOT give them any money! Further, it is almost always best to apply for visas yourself, not via an agent.

Comment: And you do not need an agent of any kind to apply for a visa to Canada.

Answer (score 3):

You are being scammed, be extremely careful. I got even my *immigration* visa without involving anyone else but the embassy and me and the amount of money required to support even an immigration is barely more. For a simply visitor visa, much less money is required and absolutely no agents! The average net income in Canada is ~3000 CAD which means this sort of money is what an average Canadian takes home in *three months*. Accordingly, quite a few Canadians do not have this much saved, according to this Statistics Canada [tweet](https://twitter.com/StatCan_eng/status/1110893025759252480):

> Average net #saving for all Canadian #households was $852 in 2018, while the highest #income quintile (the top 20% income earners in Canada) saved $41,393 per household.

8000 CAD is awful lot of money, in short.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a certain amount required, you just need to show you can support yourself:

> Temporary residents must have evidence that they can support themselves and any accompanying dependants while in Canada. That evidence may include one of the following:
>
> - cash, certified cheque, bank draft or money order in an amount large enough to cover all reasonable expenses to be incurred during the stay in Canada
> - verbal or written statements, which can be confirmed, that satisfy an officer that 
>     sufficient financial support from friends and/or family is available and has been arranged to adequately cover all reasonable expenses to be incurred during the stay in Canada.

([Source](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/visitors/proof-funds-financial-support.html))